# I cannot create a HTTPS server

Tags: java, ssl, serversocket

I am trying to create a HTTPS server that takes an input and outputs html, I have already made a HTTP server, however I am now trying to understand how HTTPS server code works.

```
import javax.net.ServerSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Date;


public class SimpleHTTPServer {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        ServerSocketFactory serverSocketFactory = SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
        ServerSocket server = serverSocketFactory.createServerSocket(8080);

        System.out.println("Listening for connection on port 8080 ....");

        while (true) {
            try (Socket socket = server.accept()) {
                Date today = new Date();
                String httpResponse = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n" + today;
                socket.getOutputStream().write(httpResponse.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code creates an output, on firefox, but the message is encrypted.
I would really appreciate it if someone can point me to a website or a video that has a good explanation on how to use SSLSeverSocket since I cannot find one; or if someone could explain it to me here.

Comment: **Are telling Firefox to use HTTPS?** BTW your response is not valid HTTP/1.1, although Firefox probably accepts it anyway once you get transport working (it is valid 1.0, though not best practice).

Comment: Hi, why is it not best practice?

Comment: In HTTP using implicit content length allows a bug somewhere _or_ attacker to undetectably truncate the data. In HTTPS after 2005 or so it _should_ be better because SSL3 or TLS detects truncation, but these layers aren't always integrated properly so it's more robust to continue using the existing and well-tested HTTP-level methods.